After spatial join of layer and table, set symbology to unique values but unique colors do not show on map of layer
I am taking Fundamentals of GIS through Coursera (UC-Davis) and on Assignment 2 where we used source data gdb to add a standalone table. After that, joined soils layer to table. Next, did spatial join for buffer stream that was previously built and for soils layer - selected 'Join one to many', match option: intersect. After running, want to change symbology to unique values in selected Fields (draining class). In symbology pane, I see the 6 separate drainage classes to be colored and can choose the color, but these are not being applied to the buffer layer although I can see that the layer does have these classes boundaries - problem they are all showing the same color (one of the color options I selected) versus unique colors. Is there a way I can check my joins or the classes to get the unique values/colors? To note, I was able to get unique colors on a different layer of just the soil type. This isn't working in the buffer layer that I created on a stream.
